# How to properly Align DIV's within DIV

Tags: html, css, css-float

As most people likely do, I have a div split into divs.
The internal divs split left and right properly, however the right div seems to follow *under* the left div:

[image]

The html seems free from obvious errors:

```css
.caption{
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}

.caption_left{
  position: static;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #CDCDC1;
  padding: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.caption_right {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<h4>[2. Previous]</h4>
<div class="caption">
  <div class="caption_left">
  Left Material
  </div>
  <div class="caption_right">
  Right Material
  </div>
</div>
<p>Some other stuff</p>
<h4>[3. Following]</h4>
```

I can't tell what's going wrong. I've done this before and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8jf4nvc8/2/)

CSS:

```
.caption{
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
}

.caption_left{
    position: static;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: #CDCDC1;
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}

.caption_right {
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: white;
    vertical-align: top;
}
p {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @KenIngram since you have `caption-left` a block element which will take its full width irrespective of the set width. Making it `float` will make it remain a part of the flow of the web page and leaves the rest space to other float element of adjust in that space.

Answer (score 2):

> use `float:left` in `caption_left`
>
> use `box-sizing` in `caption_left` and `caption_right`
>
> use `clear:both` for `P` :The clear property specifies on which sides of an element floating elements are not allowed to float.

```css
.caption {

    width: 100%;
    position: static;

}

.caption_left {

    float: left;
    position: static;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: #CDCDC1;
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.caption_right {

    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

p {

    clear: both;
 
}
```

```html
<h4>[2. Previous]</h4>


<div class="caption">
  <div class="caption_left">
  Left Material
  </div>
  <div class="caption_right">
  Right Material
  </div>
</div>
<p>Some other stuff</p>


<h4>[3. Following]</h4>
```